# Drag and Drop panel with label

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using WinForms that has a drag and drop feature.  Right now it is event based and I have no problems dragging the panel around and keeping the label attached to the the panel.  However, when I click on the **label**, in this case a number, I can't get it to raise both drag and drop events for the label and the panel at the same time, so nothing can be moved.

My thoughts to solve this were binding coordinates of the label (.Text is always 1-9) to the label coordinates.

My other thought is to create a custom UI component that would have a constructor like Tile(string labelText) which would "hide" the fact the label is there, so I would just have to use the Panel's drag and drop event.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something **like**:

```
private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    panel1_MouseDown(null, null);
}
```

Comment: This will work though I wouldn't pass in the nulls I would use `panel1_MouseDown(panel1, e);` instead